# Ajax error - 500 internal server error when request an external page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a problem with ajax.
this is my code to load a page or a part of it in a div.

```
  $("a").click(function (event) {
  var Rel = $(this).attr("rel");//The class name want to load from Default2.aspx
  if (Rel) {
      $('.Content_Part').load("Default2.aspx ." + Rel )
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  });
```

my current page name is "Default.aspx" and the target page is "Default2.aspx", the problem is when i want to load something from Default2.aspx occur an error "500 internal server error" but when i want to load something from Default.aspx everything is OK.
for more information:
 i have a div in default.aspx with class name "Content_Part" and i want to load a Table from default2.aspx with class name for example "myTable" into "Content_Part".
i was using this function and it works fine but after 1 hour this problem occurred.
what's the problem?

Comment: What error message are you getting from the "500 Internal Server Error" on Default2?

Answer (score 0):

**BTW not answer to your question, but you should handle the ajax error.**

```
<script>
 $('.Content_Part').load("Default2.aspx ." + Rel, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
</script>
```